# Embed Flutter inside a cocoapod and use it in the main project

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, cocoapods

I have a requirement where there is an existing project which uses a pod which is also internally created.

For simplicity we will call app as MyApp and internal pod as MyPod.

So MyApp depends on MyPod.

Now the requirement is to add flutter screen in MyPod.
I am using Option B as mentioned in the flutter guide to achieve this.
https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#option-b---embed-frameworks-in-xcode

Now the problem that I am facing is that the MyPod is building fine. But when I try to build MyApp it throws compilation error that "import Flutter" not found inside the MyPod file.

Any idea on how to achieve this scenario or any clue on how to resolve this issue.